# wrong object data when windows store app is resumed

Tags: c#, windows-store-apps

I have a **windows store app** developed using C#, XAML. The app is used by doctors to note down patients data. One of the feature of this app is supposed to pause the patient inspection when app is suspended. Basically, all the patient **data is stored in a xml**, so when the app is suspended (OnSuspending event) the **data is serialized to xml and stored in local data folder**.

The issue we are facing is that when the app is resumed and doctor resumes the task, the **data loaded is incorrect** in the sense that some other patients data is loaded instead of the one doctor was actually working on.

Note that **we haven't handled the OnResumed event** and no code is written there. I am not sure if that is required because when debugging I always see the correct objects still in memory.

**My question is that it is really necessary to restore the objects explicitly in such cases? 
Why the object is wrong in some cases?**

Thanks!

Comment: This article describe your issue?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12212831/saving-data-during-the-onsuspending-method

Comment: When and how is the incorrect data being loaded? 
If you examine the serialised XML file on disk is it correct?

OnResumed shouldn't be necessary in your case: the app's memory is retained when suspending and resuming. You need to save the data and restore it only if the app is suspended, terminated, and relaunched. 

Debugging suspension is a bit tricky since the app won't suspend on its own when a debugger is attached. You'll need to use Visual Studio's suspend button on the debugging toolbar to mimic this.

Comment: Thanks Rob. If there is no need to restore the object, then there is definitely something else going on that is causing the wrong object to be loaded. I will review the code once again and get back to you.