# Using CreateFileAsync On Windows 8

Tags: c#, file-io, windows-8

I am trying to save some simple data in my C# Windows 8 application, however, I can't seem to get any of the async file operations to work.

I can write:

```
ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.CreateFileAsync(...);
```

however, if I add an await command in front of that and attempt to convert it into the form:

```
StorageFile file = await ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.CreateFileAsync(...);
```

I start getting compiler errors. Specifically that that await operator can only be used with async operations. Since the operation is async I'm a bit confused.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The method in which your async call (in this case `CreateFileAsync`) must be marked `async` in order for you to call an async method with `await`.

See the question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11996288/storagefolder-createfileasync-crashes-when-called-from-app-onsuspending) for a properly formed method in which to call an async method with `await`.

Comment: Ah, thanks, I spent 2 days searching for an answer. Apparently I need a different search engine or to refine my search. Thanks again.